# Would it be wasteful to put 1000px pictures in 100px mobile web pages,In mobile phones with device pixel ratio of 2

Tags: css, image, aspect-ratio

I'm a little confused about the device pixel ratio.If I use a 1000px image to represent a 100px CSS with a cell phone pixel ratio of 2, is it a waste of 800 pixels? If not, one CSS pixel represents 10 physical pixels.

Comment: Short answer is yes – a x2 pixel ratio means the device will use 200px to display a 100px (CSS) image. If you make the image larger it will be scaled/interpolated down to match the 200. To make it use less bandwidth and load faster it's always a good idea to keep your image size as close to what you expect the dp to be.